# Can't understand why onClick not working in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, jsx

I have code in JSX:

```js
    {data.map(({ id }) => (
           <div key={id}
                id={id}
                onClick={() => handleClick(id)}
           >

           </div>
    ))}
```

It does not work after rendering and I do not understand why. However, if I write `onClick={handleClick(id)}` it will work, but only once when it's redndering and never more. Below is `handleClick` code:

```
export default function handleClick(id) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
       console.log(id);
    }
}
```

How can I make `handleClick` each time I click on the `div`?

Comment: I presume the capital L in `handleCLick` is just a typo in the question and not the cause of the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is a typo

Comment: Please show us how you import the function, how you connect it to the component and how/if you destructure it from the props ? (*perhaps it should be `this.props.handleClick` if it is a class component ?*)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to dispatch a redux async action creator. You can't dispatch directly from a HTML element `onClick` handler. If you [bind the redux action creators](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators) it should work as expected.

In your component mount:

```
actionCreators = bindActionCreators({ handleClick }, dispatch);
```

In your render function:

```
onClick={() => actionCreators.handleClick(id)}
```

If you were not trying to use redux, you can log the id with a different click handler:

```
function handleClick(id) {
  // return mouse event handler for onClick
  return (event) => {
    console.log(id);
  }
}

onClick={handleClick(id)}
```

If you want the fastest way to log the `id` you can use inline click handler too:

```
onClick={() => console.log(id)}
```

If you were trying to use redux but the redux async action creator is not firing, it's possible your `onClick` handler is fine but the redux store is not configured to handle async actions. The fix is to find where the redux store is created and call `applyMiddleware` with the async thunk middleware.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

Comment: no, I connect function through the dispatcher, I just did not show it in the code

Comment: @IWProgrammer its possible your redux store does not have the async thunk middleware. You might need `applyMiddleware` to the store. By default it will not handle async actions. https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware#example-using-thunk-middleware-for-async-actions

Comment: I use middleware

Comment: Is it possible the div has `pointer-events: none` or another CSS rule that would prevent clicking? Can you confirm that a simple inline `onClick` handler that logs the `id` shows up in the dev tools console?

Comment: Your code looks correct. I would bet it's a problem with action creator binding or redux thunk middleware not working as expected. If you log `handleClick` function itself does it look like a bound action creator or the original function signature?

Comment: but I use the same for `onChange` event and it works